# Python Maya select shape in shape editor / vertex index

Tags: python, command, maya, shapes, vertex

I want to select shape in shape editor with Python code but I don't know how. I need to select my shape for use `performTargetShapeFlip`.
The problem is I cannot find the code for select a shape in shape editor because this flip is a command to the shape editor.

And I want to memory with command the vertex index ex :`(vtx[0]=[0,1,0])` for memory the base geometry and be able to reset my geometry.
But I don't know how I can't code that.
I tried `polyEvaluate` but he take the number of object vertex.

Comment: the shape editor is the blendshape editor, right ? I dont understand what you want to do :/  Could you provide an example of the command you want to "pythonize". If you want to query vertices, use ls '.vtx[:]' combine to pointPosition or xform

Comment: Yes this is it,
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-CharacterAnimation/files/GUID-92276800-7F50-4A24-B365-D504B0F69E49-htm.html

Comment: okay now, can you explain what you want to do exactly ? The command of the flip result into the mel : performTargetShapeFlip 0; and doBlendShapeFlipTarget 4 1 {}. If you want to see what does these commands, you can do : whatIs performTargetShapeFlip; it will return the path where the script is located or whatIs doBlendShapeFlipTarget;

Comment: note that I've opened the two files and your answer is in whatIs doBlendShapeFlipTarget;

Comment: I know that but i need to select the right shape for flip.

Comment: you need your cmds.blendShape(), you can query your targets and there is even a flipTarget flag. Everything is written in the mel file otherwise. If you are stuck somewhere, try to provide some code you have written